# Asp.net Button Added in UpdatePanel dones not click

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I've an UpdatePanel where according to operations inside of this UP is filled. 
I've add some buttons but the buttons to not fire clicks.

I've used the code

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Click += new EventHandler(ClickMe);

...
void ClickMe(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: On what stage of the page life cycle  did you add buttons?

Comment: While i'm working in updatepanel, i make extra things and i add buttons

Comment: you need to make sure that you recreate this button before it is clicked.

Comment: If i click the button it never calls its eventhandler.

Comment: What Tim was trying to say is that the button has to be recreated during the pages page_init event or the click event handler will never be called

Answer (score 0):

Forget adding event handlers programmatically through code - make your life easier and add directly inside the ASPX source, e.g:

This will trigger your "ClickMe" event in your code behind.

If, however, you're going pure programmatic, override the CreateChildControls method, like so:

```
   protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        b.Click += new EventHandler(MyClick);
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
```

Comment: I have to add them dynamically.

Comment: If you are adding buttons dynamically at run time, consider instead adding all buttons to the ASPX source and hiding/unhiding dynamically. This is a fair approach provided you don't have lots and lots of buttons...

Comment: If you are going the pure programmatic route - make sure you do your button click event assignment inside the CreateChildControls method.

Comment: Okay, it is nice to override the function but how can i access my button from a lower level ? my button is created dynamically !

Comment: What do you mean a 'lower level'? Post up some of your code in your question above and I will see what I can make of it.

Comment: Are you making sure you add the button inside your update panel? You need to make sure you add the button to the Controls collection of your update panel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've to programmatically add a trigger to the UpdatePanel:

The code should be something like (not tested):

```
AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
trigger.ControlID = b.UniqueID;
trigger.EventName = "Click";
yourUpdPanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);

ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(b);
```

Comment: your code does not work. i want to add a button does not matter if it updates the panel or not. i need it clicks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that works. You need to make sure that your button is added on every postback.

Markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="litMessage" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = "Click me";
    button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);

    updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(button);
}

protected void button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litMessage.Text = ((Button)sender).Text + " clicked.";
}
```

Comment: there is a problem ! you add button with override function. But I add at different times in different counts buttons and i have more than one updatepanels so that for which one i can use this function ? this is not a good solution